# How to set current value in a QCombobox

Tags: qt

I've a basic question. I've `QComboBox`, as follows:

```
   ui->comboBox_1->addItem("200ms", QVariant(0.2));
   ui->comboBox_1->addItem("500ms", QVariant(0.5));
   ui->comboBox_1->addItem("1000ms", QVariant(1));
   ui->comboBox_1->addItem("1500ms", QVariant(1.5));
   ui->comboBox_1->addItem("2000ms", QVariant(2));
```

How do I set the current value?
for example I want combo box to show `1500ms` when the program starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filling `combobox`, set the current index through `setCurrentIndex()`

```
ui->comboBox_1->setCurrentIndex(3);
```

So your code becomes

```
ui->comboBox_1->addItem("200ms", QVariant(0.2));
ui->comboBox_1->addItem("500ms", QVariant(0.5));
ui->comboBox_1->addItem("1000ms", QVariant(1));
ui->comboBox_1->addItem("1500ms", QVariant(1.5));
ui->comboBox_1->addItem("2000ms", QVariant(2));
ui->comboBox_1->setCurrentIndex(3);
```